# Kohana - AJAX - Authenticate to a model with no database

Tags: php, ajax, forms, authentication, kohana

Well I'm going crazy here. This is something that seems like it should be so simple and maybe it's just staring me in the face and I'm not seeing it. I have specific instructions to make a login page in Kohana 3.2 that uses AJAX to process the form and authenticate just to the model with a plain text username and password. It's just an exercise clearly designed to embarrass me, hehe. So no, security is not an issue here. There is no database and no content to be exploited.

I currently have the login form working just using Auth using the default 'file' driver in the auth config file.

**application/config/auth.php**

```
  return array(

    'driver'       => 'file',
    'hash_method'  => 'sha256',
    'hash_key'     => 'testkey',
    'lifetime'     => 30000,
    'session_type' => Session::$default,
    'session_key'  => 'auth_user',

    // Username/password combinations for the Auth File driver
    'users' => array(
                    'admin' => 'be4039381cf04bb778de68e6520a77c7d8b5e6d146f932f0759e681a46bfc120',
                    ),

);
```

However I have been searching and searching for an example of how to change this to submit and authorize using AJAX. I'm swimming in a sea of is_ajax and Controller_Templates etc. I've used Kohana for approximately 28 hours now. Will anyone help me figure this out?

**application/views/user/login.php**

```
<?= Form::open('user/login',array('class'=>'form-signin')); ?>
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign in</h2>
<?php if (isset($message)) : ?>
    <h3 class="message">
        <?= $message; ?>
    </h3>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Username Field -->
<?php $uArray = array('type'=>'text','class'=>'input-block-level','placeholder'=>'Username = admin'); ?>
<?= Form::input('username',NULL,$uArray); ?>

<!-- Password Field -->
<?php $pwArray = array('class'=>'input-block-level', 'placeholder'=>'Password = password'); ?>
<?= Form::password('password',NULL,$pwArray); ?>

<!-- Checkbox -->
<?= Form::checkbox('remember','remember'); ?>
<?= Form::label('remember', 'Remember Me',array('class'=>'checkbox','label'=>'Remember')); ?>
<br />

<!-- Submit Buton -->
<?= Form::submit('login', 'Login',array('class'=>'btn btn-large btn-primary')); ?>

<?= Form::close(); ?>
```

**application/classes/controller/user.php**

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_User extends Controller_Template {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->template->content = View::factory('user/index');
        // Load the user information
        $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();
        // if a user is not logged in, redirect to login page
        if ($user)
        {
            $this->template->content = View::factory('user/welcome')
            ->bind('user', $user);
        }
    }

    public function action_login()
    {
        // if a user is already logged in then redirect them to the index.
        if (Auth::instance()->logged_in())
            {
                // User is logged in, continue on
                Request::current()->redirect('user/index');
            }

        $this->template->content = View::factory('user/login')
            ->bind('message', $message);

        if (HTTP_Request::POST == $this->request->method())
        {
            // Attempt to login user
            $remember = array_key_exists('remember', $this->request->post()) ? (bool) $this->request->post('remember') : FALSE;
            $user = Auth::instance()->login($this->request->post('username'), $this->request->post('password'), $remember);

            // If successful, redirect user
            if ($user)
            {
                $this->template->content = View::factory('user/welcome')
                ->bind('user', $user);
            }
            else
            {
                $message = 'Login failed';
            }
        }
    }

    public function action_logout()
    {
        // Log user out
        Auth::instance()->logout();

        // Redirect to login page
        Request::current()->redirect('user/login');
    }

}
```

**application/classes/model/user.php**

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No Direct Script Access');
```

I am unfamiliar enough with Kohana that I'm not even sure what to put in the model. Right now Auth is using it's own file to store the users array. But my instructions are to have a model store the username and password.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Not that this comment helps your situation much, but please try to not do this: <? $pwArray instead always declare php: <?php $pwArray

Comment: @KaiQing You're right of course. It's an old and bad habit. Already fixed in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out last night. I'll answer my own question for future reference. While I'm still using Auth to handle the user session I am not authenticating to it. I'm using

```
Auth::instance()->force_login($username)
```

to force the login after authenticating to the model as I was asked to do.

First I changed my login page to simplify and to add some AJAX.

**/application/views/user/login.php**

```
<form id="loginForm" class="form-signin">

<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign in</h2>

<div class="message" id="message"></div>

<!-- Username Field -->
<input type="text" id="username" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username = admin" />

<!-- Password Field -->
<input type="password" id="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password = password" />

<!-- Submit Buton -->
<input type="submit" id="login" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" />

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#login").click(function() {
        var action = $("#loginForm").attr('action');
        var form_data = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            is_ajax: 1
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/user/checkLogin',
            data: form_data,
            success: function(response)
            {
                if(response == 'success')
                    window.location.replace('/user');
                else
                    $("#message").html("<div class='alert alert-error'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button>Invalid username and/or password.</div>");    
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Then I added a simple model with plaintext username and password. (again this is prrof of concept and is by no means meant to be a secure way to authenticate).

**/application/classes/model/user.php**

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No Direct Script Access');

Class Model_User extends Model
{
    public function checkLogin($username, $password)
    {
        // These are the username and password to verify against
        $user = "admin";
        $pass = "password";

        // Compare and return boolean
        if ($username === $user && $password === $pass){
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added the checkLogin action to the user controller (because that's what I'm calling from my AJAX on the login page) to handle the login.

**/application/classes/controller/user.php**

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_User extends Controller_Template {

    public function action_index()
    {
        // Load the user information
        $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();

        // if a user is logged in, redirect to welcome page
        if ($user){
            $this->template->content = View::factory('user/welcome')
            ->bind('user', $user);
        } else {
            $this->template->content = View::factory('user/index');
        }
    }

    public function action_checkLogin()
    {
        //disable auto rendering if requested using ajax
        if($this->request->is_ajax()){
            $this->auto_render = FALSE;
        }

        // Check for post
        if($this->request->post()){
            // Instantiate the Model Object
            $user = new Model_User();

            // Get post variables
            $username = $this->request->post('username');
            $password = $this->request->post('password');

            // Check the login
            if($check = $user->checkLogin($username,$password)){
                // Login the user using auth
                $user = Auth::instance()->force_login($username);
                // Respond with a success
                echo 'success';
            } else {
                // Respond with a fail
                return "fail";
            }
        }
    }

    public function action_login()
    {
        // Load the user information
        $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();

        // if a user is logged in, redirect to welcome page
        if ($user){
            $this->template->content = View::factory('user/welcome')
            ->bind('user', $user);
        } else {
            $this->template->content = View::factory('user/login')
            ->bind('message', $message);
        }
    }

    public function action_logout()
    {
        // Log user out
        Auth::instance()->logout();

        // Redirect to login page
        Request::current()->redirect('user/login');
    }

}
```

Now I have a nice simple login page that authenticates to the model using AJAX in the Kohana framework. It's not rocket surgery but it's interesting to figure out how these various frameworks function. Hope it helps someone in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this answer to try to communicate as a comment with code, not necessarily to serve as an answer. That said:

Is this working for you?

```
public function action_index()
    {
        $this->template->content = View::factory('user/index')
            ->bind('user', $user);
```

$user is not defined there, so I would assume that would cause an error.
Also, I'm not sure where your user model comes into play here. If there is no database tied to user, then kohana does not depend on a user model like it would if you were using the ORM. So, why the need to store anything in a model instance if that instance is only going to be tossed when the page changes? Assuming it means on login you say something like `$user = new User_Model();` then assign private vars or something.

And this "But my instructions are to have a model store the username and password." what is the goal of this person's request? To teach you? Or to have the user info available if logged in?

Comment: Fair enough, now the question of intention. What is the goal of having a user model having these vars available? I ask cause if it is just like a session thing then you can just extend auth or have your user model autoload if logged in.

Comment: Yes that does actually work. However you bring up a good point and there's no need to bind user there if it's not even defined and the only time I'm sending the user there is if they are not logged in thus not defined. I have modified the line to remove the bind method. And also the reason for the request is I think a bit of a test/teach moment. So I'm trying to comply. I'm actually disappointed in the documentation and examples available for the Kohana framework. I learn best when I can see an example of how something is done and then pick apart the pieces and see what effects what.

Comment: Yeah, kohana docs might not be too helpful as far as examples go, but there are plenty of examples available. I learned by examples, not by reading their docs. But you still don't clarify what the goal is. What is the end goal of the user model?

Comment: Oh Sorry about that. The end goal of using a Model I think is really just for me to show full MVC usage I think. It would be easier at this point for me if I were using ORM and MySQL.